# What proficiency gives you spell attack modifiers?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, proficiency

So I'm just starting out in DND and I'm confused about what allows a character to have proficiency bonuses in spellcasting.

For example my level 1 Ranger has a +2 on shortbow attacks because he's proficient in simple weapons.

How could I get a +2 in spellcasting, by being proficient in what? Because the Wizard/Sorceror don't have a simple proficiency like "spells".

Comment: Hi, and welcome to RPG.se! This site is a bit different to other sites, so please take the [tour](/tour) (you get a badge for doing it, too). Just so you know, the tag [dungeons-and-dragons](/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) should be used to refer to the series of games as a whole, and questions more like this one should refer to a specific edition, such as [dnd-5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-5e). I've updated the tags on your question so it will be easer for people to find. Check out our [help center](/help) for more information.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## All spellcasters are proficient with spell attacks.

There is no specific proficiency for spell attacks. Instead, the general rule for spell attack rolls is:

> Your attack bonus with a spell attack equals your spellcasting ability modifier + your proficiency bonus.

(PHB, p.205)

So: *Any* character that casts a spell that requires an attack roll is "proficient", and adds their proficiency bonus. This includes spells cast by means of a magic item, or spells cast without using spell slots from class or racial features.

Comment: The above holds true even if the spell is originated from an item or some unusual feature. All spell attacks are made with proficiency.

Comment: Exactly so, which is why the answer says "Any character that casts a spell". Do you think that needs more emphasis or clarification?

Comment: Maybe, probably yes. Some people only think the character has *"cast a spell"* if he spends a *spell slot*. I've had one such discussion last month at a RPG gathering. After almost an hour of heated debate, we came to the conclusion that even if the character has no spellcasting features, he still adds proficiency.

Comment: @Mindwin Done, thanks for the feedback! Let me know if it needs more work.

Comment: @Marq You should point out that if you don't have a spellcasting ability you do not get the spellcasting ability modifier (you always get the proficiency bonus) see DMG p.141

Comment: If we look at Feats, the Feat (Elemental Adept) Source: PHB, page 166, has a prerequisite of Spellcasting.  Prerequisite: The ability to cast at least one spell. so it must be a proficiency to get, else why it's a prerequisite ?

Comment: @HuguesGauthier Feat prerequisites don’t have to be proficiencies, and the ability to cast at least one spell is exactly that and nothing more; I don’t see how a proficiency is implied in this case.